# C++ STL: Why allocators don't increase memory footprint of containers?

Tags: c++, stl, allocator

The following code snippet([see on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/jqcx1xff1)) shows that big allocators won't increase the memory footprint of STL containers, but big comparators will. Why is it the case?

```c++
// compiled with x86-64 gcc 10.3, -std=c++17
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <set>

struct MyLess : public std::less<int>
{
    char dummy[1024];
};

struct MyAllocator : public std::allocator<int>
{
    char dummy[1024];
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << sizeof(std::set<int, MyLess>) << std::endl;  // prints 1064
    std::cout << sizeof(std::set<int, std::less<int>, MyAllocator>) << std::endl;  // prints 48
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your allocator is not being used.

By default, `std::set` receives `std::allocator<int>`, but it needs to allocate some kind of nodes, not `int`s. It uses [`std::allocator_traits::rebind`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator_traits) to get a different allocator for its internal node type.

Pre-C++20 [`std::allocator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator) has a `rebind` member type, which you inherit, and which `std::allocator_traits::rebind` finds. That `rebind` points to `std::allocator`, so that's what you get.

Starting from C++20, there's no `rebind` in `std::allocator`, so `std::allocator_traits::rebind` falls back to directly modifying the first template parameter of your allocator, and since it's not a template, you get a compilation error.

A possible solution is to make your allocator a template, and to provide your own `rebind` (which can be malformed, then the template parameter will be replaced automatically):

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct MyAllocator : public std::allocator<T>
{
    char dummy[1024];
    struct rebind {}; // Malformed `rebind` to hide the inherited one, if any.
};
```

Then `1072` is printed for me.